# SQL transactions run on Postgres 9.0 but one is aborted on SQLServer 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql, serialization, transactions

Suppose we try to run concurrently the following two transactions:

```
T1:
BEGIN
  UPDATE place
  SET state_code=5
  WHERE state_code=6
  AND type='town'
COMMIT

T2:
BEGIN
  UPDATE place
  SET state_code=6
  WHERE state_code=5
  AND type='town'
COMMIT
```

On Postgres 9.0 the transactions complete successfully. However, when run on a SQLServer 2005 T1 gets aborted, thus all states end up with state_code=5.

1. Which DBMS did/did not obey strict transaction serialisation and why?
2. What settings might or might not have been set in each DBMS to cause this behaviour?

Comment: Sounds like a homework assignment.

Comment: And what is the error message in SQL Server?

Comment: It is unclear what the *expected* result is. Is the intent to transpose the values? Or to set them to be the same? Both outcomes are possible in `READ COMMITTED` or `SNAPSHOT` isolation, depending on the exact execution ordering.

Answer (score 2):

MS SQL uses transaction statments as:

```
BEGIN transaction
  UPDATE place
  SET state_code=5
  WHERE state_code=6
  AND type='town'
COMMIT
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that doesn't really help. The syntax of the transactions is irrelevant.

Comment: Are you trying to run the obove code on MS SQL? Cos in that case you will get an error

Comment: The question tests theory. Assume the behaviours occur as mentioned.

Comment: Then we need more info on this to help you. Can you make an example of the false behavior with MS SQL code mybe some test data and table create script?

Comment: best answer to this then is that POSTGRESQL and MSSQL have different syntax for transactions and terefore the same code can not work the code provided by you works on POSTGRESQL cos it consists with its syntax but can not work on MSSQL

Comment: Thanks, but it is assumed that the transactions are correct in syntax.

Comment: What kind of error Should you get from MSSQL? What are the table definitons for this? Cos as the update stands it should work asuming the field types consists with the provided statment

Comment: There's no error reported. T1 is aborted by the DBMS and hence all records end up with state_code=5.

Comment: I'll have a look, I've found this link, which is useful: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/transaction-iso.html

Answer (score 1):

In PostgreSQL you can test this by using a table-level lock to ensure that the competing transactions run concurrently. Setup:

```
CREATE TABLE place (id serial primary key, state_code integer, type text);
INSERT INTO place (state_code, type) VALUES (5, 'town'), (6, 'town');
```

Then in a session T0:

```
BEGIN; LOCK TABLE place;
```

In two new sessions issue the commands for T1 and T2.

Now back in T0 issue:

```
ROLLBACK;
```

to release the table-level lock and allow T1 and T2 to race.

In `READ COMMITTED` isolation (the default) both will be transposed... though in the real world this will depend on the exact ordering of the transactions and cannot be relied upon.

In `REPEATABLE READ`, (called `SERIALIZABLE` isolation in PostgreSQL 9.0) they will both be transposed, with the same caveat as with `READ COMMITTED` since both are essentially equivalent for single statement transactions; the snapshot is taken when the first statement is run, not at the `BEGIN`.

In `SERIALIZABLE` isolation, set via `default_transaction_isolation` GUC or `BEGIN TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE`, one transaction will fail to commit with a serialization failure while the other will succeed, resulting in all rows having `state_code` 5, or all rows having `state_code` 6, depending on which transaction won.

If SQL Server also aborts one of the transactions, then it's doing proper serialization.

SQL Server obeyed proper serialization (as would a current version of PostgreSQL when strict serialization is requested), while the tested version of PostgreSQL was set to either `READ COMMITTED` isolation (where it isn't supposed to serialize) or pre-9.1's `SERIALIZABLE` isolation  (which could not detect this anomaly) and did *not* obey strict transaction serialization semantics.

This could be experienced in PostgreSQL 9.2 if `default_transaction_isolation` is set to anything except `SERIALIZABLE`, and was the norm before PostgreSQL 9.1.

It looks like SQL Server uses [`SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx). In PostgreSQL you use the [`default_transaction_isolation` GUC](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-DEFAULT-TRANSACTION-ISOLATION) or [`SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-set-transaction.html). It isn't clear if SQL Server lets you set a default transaction isolation level globally.